# Fill empty values in a dataframe based on columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe `df1` like this.

[image]

I want to fill the `nan` and the number `0` in column `score` with mutiple values in another dataframe `df2` according to the different names.

[image]

How could I do this?

Comment: Thanks for accepting! Remember you can also upvote answers, so please consider upvoting the other answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
Short version

```
df1.score = df1.score.mask(df1.score.eq(0)).fillna(
    df1.name.map(df2.set_index('name').score)
)
df1

  name  score
0    A   10.0
1    B   32.0
2    A   10.0
3    C   30.0
4    B   20.0
5    A   45.0
6    A   10.0
7    A   10.0
```

---

**Option 2**
Interesting version using `searchsorted`.  `df2` must be sorted by `'name'`.

```
i = np.where(np.isnan(df1.score.mask(df1.score.values == 0).values))[0]
j = df2.name.values.searchsorted(df1.name.values[i])
df1.score.values[i] = df2.score.values[j]
df1

  name  score
0    A   10.0
1    B   32.0
2    A   10.0
3    C   30.0
4    B   20.0
5    A   45.0
6    A   10.0
7    A   10.0
```

Comment: 1st time notice `fillna` can be in this way , thank you :)+1

Answer (score 2):

If `df1` and `df2` are your dataframes, you can create a mapping and then call `pd.Series.replace`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
                     'score': [0, 32, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 45, np.nan, np.nan]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'score' : [10, 20, 30]})

print(df1)

  name  score
0    A    0.0
1    B   32.0
2    A    0.0
3    C    NaN
4    B    NaN
5    A   45.0
6    A    NaN
7    A    NaN

print(df2) 

  name  score
0    A     10
1    B     20
2    C     30

mapping = dict(df2.values)

df1.loc[(df1.score.isnull()) | (df1.score == 0), 'score'] =\
               df1[(df1.score.isnull()) | (df1.score == 0)].name.replace(mapping)

print(df1)

  name  score
0    A   10.0
1    B   32.0
2    A   10.0
3    C   30.0
4    B   20.0
5    A   45.0
6    A   10.0
7    A   10.0
```

Comment: dude! `dict(df2.values)` is pretty slick.  I'll be stealing... borrowing that.

Comment: @piRSquared By all means!

Answer (score 1):

Or using `merge`, `fillna`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1.loc[df.score==0,'score']=np.nan
df1.merge(df2,on='name',how='left').fillna(method='bfill',axis=1)[['name','score_x']]\
    .rename(columns={'score_x':'score'})
```

Answer (score 1):

This method changes the order (the result will be sorted by `name`).

```
df1.set_index('name').replace(0, np.nan).combine_first(df2.set_index('name')).reset_index()

  name  score
0    A     10
1    A     10
2    A     45
3    A     10
4    A     10
5    B     32
6    B     20
7    C     30
```